# What does this button on the geoscape in Mission Control do?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

When viewing the geoscape in Mission Control, there's a button in the bottom left that seems to toggle the map between the normal view, and a digital-looking blue view.

[image]
[image]

Does this have any effect other than pretty colors?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It makes the globe display some situation room data like the panic level of the council nations - for example, there's some yellow in the south-east of the globe in that screenshot (Brazil), that would seem to indicate some medium panic levels.

Comment: but why is the globe stuck?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is supposed to show panic level by country but, at least in my game, the colors are wrong

like right now in the situation room I'm getting blue for china, but in mission control when I click that china is yellow

either a bug or it means something else

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding text when in gamepad control mode is Hologlobe, so I'm guessing it just looks cool.

Comment: And it does look cool.